# Одинаков ли смысл

Tags: семантика

Прошу пояснить вытекает ли из сымсла первой фразы вторая.является одинаков ли смысл у следующих фраз.
**«К гражданскому оружию относится оружие, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятий спортом и охоты»,** 
и
«Газовые баллончики, принадлежащие В.Т. (инициалы – тому, кто интересовался) является гражданским оружием, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятия спортом, охоты.»,

Контекст таков.
*Я бы хотел, уточнив некоторые детали, задать дополнительный вопрос Елене (большое спасибо), давшей мне ответ.
Я передал газовые баллончики, предназначенные для самообороны, в специализированный магазин, для реализации. Правоохранительные органы, узнав о моих действиях, изъяли данный вид оружия на основании следующего закона: «К гражданскому оружию относится оружие, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятий спортом и охоты», предварительно его подкорректировав таким образом, что бы закон имел прямое отношение к баллончикам: «Газовые баллончики, принадлежащие В.Т. (инициалы – тому, кто интересовался) является гражданским оружием, предназначенное для использования гражданами в целях самообороны, для занятия спортом, охоты.», указав на то, что я изменил их целевое назначение. По мнению правоохранительных органов, использование баллончиков в целях самообороны, значит, для своих личных нужд, без права продажи. Спасибо*

Answer (score 1):

Это Вам не на наш форум,а к юристам. Есть сайты, где дают бесплатные консультации. Почитайте сам закон.

http://www.zakonrf.info/zoboruzhii/3/

http://www.zakonrf.info/zoboruzhii/6/

http://www.zakonrf.info/zoboruzhii/18/

http://www.zakonrf.info/zoboruzhii/28/

http://qwas.ru/russia/nbp-info/id_1297155)- здесь объясняется, что нельзя продавать(запрещён оборот)
 газового, снаряженного нервно-паралитическими, отравляющими, а также другими веществами, не разрешенными Минздравом, а также газового, способного причинить средней тяжести вред здоровью человека, находящегося на расстоянии более одного метра.

Другие виды газового оружия не запрещены к обороту. Другое дело, что  продавать гражданское оружие, а газовые баллончики к нему относятся точно, имеют право только специализированные магазины, т.е. Вы не имеете право продавать их магазину. Видимо, правоохранительные органы всё-таки имели право изъять газовые баллончики, проданные Вами магазину.Это правонарушение. А нюансы нужно узнавать у юристов.